# Laravel5.1 eloquent slow action

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

i add few Model and one Controller.

**Controller**

Forum:

```
public function showCategory($alias)
{
    $page_title = trans('forum.forum').' :: '.trans('static.website_title');

    $category_info = ForumCategory::where('category_alias', $alias)->first();

    return view('layout.pages.forum.category', compact('category_info'));
}
```

**Models**

ForumCategory

```
public function threads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum\ForumThread', 'category_id');
}
```

ForumThread

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum\ForumPost', 'thread_id');
}
```

category.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout.default')

@section('content')

{{ $category_info->category_alias }}

{{--*/ $ThreadList = $category_info->threads()->paginate(20) /*--}}

    @foreach( $ThreadList as $thread )
    {{--*/ $a = $thread->posts->count() /*--}}
        <a href="{{URL::to('/forum', array($category_info->category_alias, $thread->thread_alias))}}">{{ $thread->thread_id }} - {{ $thread->thread_subject }} - {{ $a }}</a><br /><br />
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Page rendering time is: ~0.701548814774 seconds.
In my opinion i think is very slow...
How I can speed this?

Comment: Install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar on dev so you *know* why it's slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to execute all the code you specified in the example, including commented lines. I think that what you're searching is **Eager Loading**.

It can be easily used to avoid the N + 1 queries problem and improve performances.

You should use something like:

```
ForumCategory::with('threads')->where('category_alias', $alias)->first();
```

Also, you can specify nested relationships.

```
ForumCategory::with('threads.posts')->where('category_alias', $alias)->first();
```

More details [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)! The documentation example is really easy to understand!

Also, it would be useful to profile your application requests using a profiler. There are many out there, [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) is one of these.

Comment: I have over 30,000 posts for one thread. I edited thread table and added thread_replay and changed in category.blade.php for this: ** $a = $thread->thread_reply+1 **

Comment: Obviously you can use [Eager Loading constraining](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) to get your job done and select only a specific set of threads. It's the same exactly syntax :)

Comment: If you want to "store" (and then get) some meta data information about your threads, you could edit the ForumThread model and add an accessor named "posts_count" that counts the total number of posts :). Take a look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

Comment: Yes I know about it, but what is better practice?

Comment: Imho, you could eager load threads and then implement an accessor inside the _ForumThread_ model.

Comment: Wait, take a look to this article: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/ it is useful to get some data about the N+1 problem (because yes, Eager Loading works but you need to get an extra count)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. But i have one question. But $thread->postsCount->first()->aggregate; not working i must create something like that: @if($cat_count = $thread->postsCount->first())
  {{ $cat_count->aggregate }}
  @endif

Comment: What error are you getting? Actually It should work :)

Comment: Also, if you read the article comments you will find some tweaks for L5.1

Comment: In ForumThread i added: `public function postsCount() { return $this->posts()->selectRaw('count(*) as aggregate')->where('post_deleted', '=', 0)->groupBy('thread_id'); } public function getPostsCountAttribute()
{ if ( ! array_key_exists('postsCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('postsCount'); $related = $this->getRelation('postsCount'); return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate : 0;}` in category.blade.php this: `{{ $thread->postsCount()->first()->aggregate }}` and not working: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: when i change `$thread->postsCount()->first()->aggregate` to `$thread->postsCount()->first()['aggregate']` it's working

Comment: Quite strange! But glad to hear that works, at least :)

Comment: Oh, don't forget to use the debugbar to have more informations about your request timing. It's not only about SQL queries, often :)

Comment: Yes it is realy strange. On this moment i use DB::enableQueryLog() and DB::getQueryLog(). Thanks :)